# using Jquery to parse xml returned from a PHP file

Tags: php, jquery

Due to white-list security I'm using a PHP script to return XML from an external server.

PHP file code looks as follows -

```
<?php

include_once 'utilityCurl.class.php';

$uri = 'http://OURSERVER/feeds/?feedID=99&c';

$response = utilityCurl::fetchContent($uri);

echo $response;
```

It uses the curl to return xml file.

I then use a jQuery ajax xml script to parse -

```
        $.ajax({ 
                    type: "GET", 
                    url: "http://fb.mobilechilli.com/chilli_news_reviews/news_feed_retrival.php", 
                    dataType: "xml", 
                    success: parseXml, 
                    error: errorMsg 

            }); 
//Once xml parsed and entered onto page - run caroufred class that makes the carousel work.     






            function parseXml(xml) 
            { 

                    $(xml).find("NewsItem").each(function() 
                    { 
                            var title = $(this).find('HeadLine').text();
                            var artist = $(this).find('NewsLineType').text();
                            var listItem = $('<p>hello '+title+'</p><p>'+artist+'</p><br/>');                               
                            $(".newsHeader").append(listItem);
                    });
                    alert("yep");

            }
            function errorMsg() { 
                    alert("error getting xml feed"); 
            } 
         });
```

Unfortunately I just get the error message displayed!

can anybody advise where i'm gong wrong?

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Did you get any error in Firebug console?

Comment: no annoyingly not -firebug states all is fine!

Comment: Does it show the request is being made, and correct response?

Comment: If i switch the datatype to php it doesnt error - but stil doesnt display anything!

Comment: Yes request is made and receives a response.  I will upload as an example

Comment: http://fb.mobilechilli.com/chilli_news_reviews/NewsReviews%20Build/news_reviews.php  this is the code

Comment: http://fb.mobilechilli.com/chilli_news_reviews/news_feed_retrival.php isn't loading for me.

Comment: Try to add some parameters to the `errorMsg` function (ex. `function errorMsg(e,f,g)`) and debug them with firebug to see the exact error message and number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json would be a lot easier to work with here.

in php dump this instead

```
echo json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml));
```

then in javascript you can just check if json.NewsItem is populated with something

Comment: sorry my knowledge of json with jquery isnt very strong, i've no idea how to call for and parse the xml file with json?  I added the echo script to the php file but still get the same error?

Comment: sorry, I missed a line in my example code. You should echo the json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml)) into your page then in javascript you get the result as json and just reference it like an object ie json.NewsItem will be an array of objects.